# Why do my user statistics say "+15810 change" when I only have "602 total reputation"?

Tags: support, reputation

I was looking at my user profile and came across a button that read: *"top 2% this quarter"*, after clicking it I saw a list of users names and their change in reputation.

On the second column it says `+15810 change`:

[image: image link]

Why does it say this if I only have `602 total reputation`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "+15810" refers to rankings. Gaining these 602 reputation points propelled you from being ranked  #18335 to being ranked #2525 this quarter.